Updating Electric Service to a 100yr+ old house
this is a house in SF Bay Area PGE is service provider.  House over a hundred years old.  Gone through many renovations.   I have opportunity to obtain property.   There are 3 levels garage Floor1 (Tenant 1) floor 2 (Tenant 2).  As far as electrical, power  is provided underground in 1-1/4” conduit the vault on sidewalk is less than 50 ft away.  Digging up or installing larger conduit would be problematic initially (perhaps years later).  2 wire 60A.  No 240V.  The incoming 2 wires (power + neutral) go to fuses then to two meters in garage.  There is a ground wire (water pipe-grnd rod) that connects to the neutral wire (pre fuse-pre meters).   There is present now a mix of romex with ground wires and knob and tube.  Yes it is messed up, but long term tenants have dealt with it apparently without major problems.
In change of ownership I would be obliged to correct this. Mostly worried and contemplating the service dilemma.  I am confident and have contacts/friends for modernizing/cleaning up wiring to both tenant floors (e.g. distribution panel, individual breakers, to loads).  Have built houses before and very capabale DIY but I know my limits, permits, codes, using skilled professionals when required,  etc.
Question is (preliminary for decision making and contacting and being more informed) prior to engaging with Electricians, I hope to get opinion on this.  Hire licensed electrician to get permits and work with PGE to (a) pull largest wires through existing conduit. I believe 3x 1/0 would be allowed in 1-1/4” existing conduit providing the house 150A 120/240.
(b) Install a new 150A main disconnect outside the garage entry door (c) go from outside disconnect 5 feet inside to a sub-panel with only two breakers 80A and 70A.  From there to the existing 2x meters.  Then run 70A to lower unit’s new circuit breaker box also to be in garage.  Then lastly run 80A to upper floor where a new circuit breaker panel would be installed,  Circuit panels would be 120A but limited to the 70A or 80A.  Years later if service is further upgraded e.g. 200A for house they could be fed by larger wires (wire path is wide open and would be in garage overhead and riser shaft to upper floor).   So 4x new panels  would be required in this scenario.
All that is to make situation better/legal for the time being and saving money for other required upgrades.
Is it crazy?  Can it work?  Just looking for initial thoughts and ideas is all.

As described your plan sounds workable, but plan review isn't really our focus here.

Having tenants means you need licensed electricians to do the work.  Contacts/friends will not be allowed to do any work, maybe ripping out old wires with the power cut off.

Usually the utility owns the wire up to the meter, (even if they make you buy it) they also own the meter itself, and you own the box the meter is in and the wire that comes out of it. So the proposed "split before the meters" would not work with most utilities. I know nothing specific about PG&E, but you should work with them to find a suitable solution they will actually connect power to, rather than building something they won't connect to. And yes, everything must be done by licensed workers when tenants are involved, per code.

Thanks for comments.  I feel more educated now, as I advance the project and meet with electricians.  Not impressed with what I saw even on PGE wiring to the two existing meters simply mounted on plywood on garage wall.  The 2 wires coming in from street via the 1-1/4 conduit go to an old fashion looking porcelain fuse bus that splits the incoming red and white wires to each of the two meters via screw in fuses.  Two wires in 4 wires out.  Funny the meters are new fancy looking smartmeters, so PGE condoned this weird setup recently.  Not impressed.

PGE doesn't care if you're impressed.

Out of sequence
Unfortunately, your proposal, while not a violation of the NEC, will not pass inspection nonetheless.  Why? Well, since we're dealing with metering here, the utility gets a say as well (it's their cash register!), and PG&E's Greenbook of service standards says the following about meter sequencing:

5.7.5. Meter and Main Service Switch Sequence
PG&E places its meters and metering equipment ahead of (i.e., on the supply
side of) the applicant’s main service disconnecting means. Figure 5-13,
“Single Meter With Main Service Switch,” Figure 5-14, “Single Meter With
Multiple Service Switches,” and Figure 5-15, “Multimeter Disconnect
Without Main Switch,” below, all provide examples of this type of
installation. Figure 5-17, “Multiple Remote Switchboard or Meter Panel
Locations,” on Page 5-35, also provides an example of meter and main service
switch sequences for large projects with multiple meter rooms or buildings.
PG&E permits exceptions to this sequence only in circumstances where
applying the electrical code requirements result in the applicant’s main
service disconnect means being installed ahead of PG&E’s metering and
metering equipment. Figure 5-16, “Multimeter Installation with Main
Disconnect Switch,” below, provides an example of this type of installation.
In these instances, an individual disconnect switch also must be installed on the load side of each meter.

Furthermore, Section 1.14(B) of the Greenbook requires the service PG&E runs to be big enough to satisfy the full ampacity of the termination box that is installed, and PG&E requires a dedicated termination enclosure on multi-meter underground services.  Furthermore, even if we could get a multi-meter assembly with a suitably small bus, we'd still have issues finding one that had test-block-bypass functionality.  (Note that feeding a separate meter from a jumpered-and-blanked socket in a multi-meter assembly is a non-starter as that mixes metered and unmetered conductors in the same gutter, which violates 6.4.4(D) point 1 in the Greenbook.)
Luckily, Eaton makes the R9007A 100A termination enclosure that will do the trick here.  With this, we pair a Midwest Electric T1210 (or Hoffman TB3R101) tapcan to make the tap for the common loads meter in (this is permitted by Exception 4 to NEC 230.40), a two-meter EUSERC meter-pack (the Siemens WEP2211 does the job here) for the tenant loads, and a 100A test-block-bypass meter-main, such as a Milbank U214MTB or a Siemens MM0202L1100EY, for the commons (garage) loads.  Obviously, you'll also need some appropriately sized conduit and the correct hubs (the R9007A requires the use of Myers/NEMA 4X hubs) for this, as well as 1/0 Al for the various hot and neutral wires.
Finally, grounding this is a bit trickier than normal as you will have grounding electrode tap conductors going off to the main grounding electrode conductor, as per 250.64(D)(1).  Since 8AWG copper is sufficient for the GEC tap conductors in this case, though, we can simply land the taps on any existing intersystem bonding termination device present, or add one if it's missing from the setup.

My response was deleted by some authority because I said Thank You.  WTH?

@jamespaul -- we say "thanks" around here by upvoting and/or accepting answers that help us :)

@jamespaul It's a Q&A site, which makes it orderly and easy-to-follow, not the pandemonium of discussion forums where good answers, bad answers and crosstalk are all tangled up.  That's why you're here instead of DIYchatroom, am I right?  That's called "good signal/noise ratio" and only happens with good rule enforcement. Not personal.  Anyway, high-rep posters can see deleted answers, so message received.

I just posted here out of blue.  Isn't this DIY?  I got inputs that's all.  Although after talking to my General Contractor friend today he said you are posting opinions and not ultimate truths anyway.  I Interpret complex marine codes for a living so I understand. As one Vet to another Thank you for your service,  OOPs can't say thank you.

I have 120V/30A service in my winter cottage.  It's surprisingly usable... Are you sure it needs "correcting"?  Although EV charging isn't going to happen beyond level 1, and that can be a problem with Bay Area commutes.
Make sure to check out Technology Connections' 2-part series on fully electrifying homes on 100A services.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zheQKmAT_a0
I would use 400A metering equipment, the cost delta is small compared to total project cost here, and it will allow an "easy mode" incremental upgrade later.PG&E doesn't like that.   Note that multi-meter equipment can have scarce availability with long lead times, it's not a "hop down to Home Depot and they have 12 competing models in stock" sort of deal. One option is to build it up out of components: gutters, single meter pans etc.
Also remember if there are any "house"/commons-space electrical loads, they will either need to a) have a separate meter, or b) solar/battery (let me come back to that). It is no longer legal to hang commons/house loads like shared washer-dryer, site lighting etc. on one tenant's meter, unless you pay the entire electric bill on that meter.
On solar/battery, the fact is a 3rd meter is costly, and the monthly PG&E minimum payments are costly.  If your house loads are minor/trivial such as lights or garage door openers, it may be lower total cost of ownership to go with a simple solar/battery system.  For lights alone, it's almost a no-brainer in the LED age, you can do the lighting circuits entirely DC and eliminate all "vampire load".  Some garage door openers and most power gates are capable of running on low voltage DC; they're a natural because they're a big impulse load (like a car starter) that runs for only a very short time, and uses a trivial amount of actual energy, which can be refilled into the battery by a panel the size of an iPad.

Next we need to talk about EV charging, because it's so easy, why pass it up?  The EV charging standard* makes the car very complex, so home charging can very simple yet capable. EVEMS / Dynamic Load Management lets the car maneuver around the house's other loads, slowing or stopping as needed to prevent panel overload. Sounds expensive, but actually it only adds a $300 sensor to an ordinary $500 hard-wired wall unit. You could do one per tenant service if parking allowed.  On that service. Really.
V2X (Vehicle To Home during power outages or Vehicle To Grid to help support grid stability) isn't ready for prime time, but California "recommends" people run 1" conduit between the panel and the EV station, so future wires can be fit when known.
* In home EV charging, Tesla is electrically compatible with J1772. Only plug shapes differ. The same can be said of European Mennekes when it's in single-phase mode.

Now let's talk about the idea that a 150A service needs to be split 70/80 amps. That is not true because of "diversity of loads" aka "Demand Factors" as NEC calls it - very low probability of both units maxed out at the same time. You're probably fine with 100A on both units.  This is decided by the Load Calculation in NEC Article 220. You can do the long-form calculation in Article 220 part 3.  But there's an alternative, simpler "per unit" calculation at NEC 220.82. To apply that to a 2-unit dwelling, 220.85 says you can use it simply by pretending you have a 3rd unit of same size, and applying the 220.84 demand factor formula.  E.G. if each apartment calculates out 93 amps, 93A x 3 x 45% = the service size you need.

Good comments on how it is possible to live on low amps (30-60).  But I am determined to remove all fuses. Have 120/240 3 wire.  And have modern romex wire throughout with circuit breakers. I am hoping I can use existing conduit to get at least 150A into garage.   Probably no planning for EV charging at this point.  Also great comment about demand factors and possibility of sizing/planning for 100A on both floors, a more common main breaker size.  I had that thought but don't know the Code like you details to your level of understanding.

@jamespaul there's other issues with your setup (and proposal), mostly having to do with PG&E themselves

Note that the OP can't go to 400A metering because that will cause PG&E to try to heavy-up his service to 400A, which requires them to do the conduit rip-and-replace job that the OP is trying to avoid.

@jamespaul -- re: your oversized comment (that will go away since it doesn't belong as an answer): PG&E requires the service disconnects to be at the meters, so there is no need for a separate emergency/"fireman's" disconnect.  And yeah, my answer may seem gold-plated, but there just isn't a way to cheap out further while still meeting PG&E's specs and preserving the UL listing of the parts involved. (PG&E cares about the UL listing on termination enclosures, for instance, or else I'd have had you swap the load lugs on the termination enclosure to two-hole stack lugs to make the tap)

Sorry if I am being dense here, I am marine engineer, so residential service is new. Not arguing just learning.  I looked at each component you identified and Greenbook manual.  Know I have current power in an enclosed garage (indoor).  Conduit is mere feet from existing 2x smartmeters.  Do I need 3R panels.  People converting one house/building to two metered residences (.e.g duplex/condo) describe simpler setups.  In pulling the new wire in existing conduit can’t it be as long as desired and inside conduit and go straight to the duplex meter (say WEP2211 A and B terminals)?

@ThreePhaseEel I think that last comment is for you.

@jamespaul -- the issue with having metering in the garage is that it means your garage now has to meet the meter room requirements in Greenbook section 5.3.4, including having a swing door directly to a public-accessible space and having bollards to protect the meter equipment from being inadvertently totaled by an errant car.  (Going to indoor equipment would be somewhat plausible if we could effectively use modular metering hardware for this, but that's kinda...not really an option because of the tapbox sizing issues)

@Harper-ReinstateMonica -- yeah, I saw :)
